# ArgumentError in YAML::dump if (what looks like a) date is invalid

Tags: ruby, yaml

Is there a way to make Psych a little dumber? If a string matches certain regular expression it tries to convert it to date and fails miserably. So far I switched to Syck for serializing but it's no longer maintained and I'm looking for better solution.

Here's an example of what's going on:

```
s = "2222-33-44" # => "2222-33-44"} 
require 'yaml' # => true 
YAML::dump s # ArgumentError: invalid date
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = 'syck' # => "syck" 
YAML::dump s # => "--- \"2222-33-44\"\n"
```

Comment: There might be a 'safe' option which turns off auto-typing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is a [known bug](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych/issues/42). It has been fixed but looks like the [version in RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/psych) is not containing the fix.

Also as the [git repository](https://github.com/tenderlove/psych) doesn't have a proper `.gemspec` is not easy way to install from the repo.

You can fork the repo and add a proper `.gemspec` and use a `Gemfile` that [points to your fork repo](http://gembundler.com/git.html).

Also you can ask kindly to [Aaron](https://github.com/tenderlove) to release the fix.